# Another counterexample for Prime Avoidance Theorem - graded version

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings

We have the following theorem:

> Let $R$ be a graded ring s.t. $R_0$ is a local ring, in which residue field is infinite. Let $I$ be an ideal generated by homogeneous elements of degree $s$. Let $J_1,...,J_n$ be ideals of $R$ s.t. none of them contains $I$. Then we can find a homogeneous element $x\in I$ of degree $s$ s.t. $x\notin J_i \ \forall i$.

My question is, can we find a counterexample that the theorem is wrong if the residue field is not infinite? Thank you.

Comment: $R=\mathbb F_2[X_1,X_2]$ and $I=(X_1,X_2)$, $P_1=(X_1)$, $P_2=(X_2)$, $P_3=(X_1+X_2)$, and $s=1$.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you. I figured it out 1 hour ago. Again, thank you